# How can I run Win Forms with .NET Core's generic host and have it control the host lifetime?

Tags: winforms, .net-core

How can I run Win Forms with .NET Core's generic host and have it control the host lifetime? I want to use the Host's default builder and use an extension method to add my startup form. I want the host to shutdown when the startup form is closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `OswaldTechnologies.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsFormsLifetime` library I wrote to accomplish this.

Install package:

```
Install-Package OswaldTechnologies.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsFormsLifetime
```

`Program` class before with default .NET Core Win Forms template:

```cs
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Transform `Program` class to the below after installing the package:

```cs
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CreateHostBuilder().Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(Array.Empty<string>())
            .UseWindowsFormsLifetime<Form1>()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                    
            });
}
```

You can view the code in the Github repo: https://github.com/alex-oswald/WindowsFormsLifetime

**Edit 2021-11-16** The library is updated for .NET 6. With the minimal API introduced, starting a Windows Forms app with the generic host only takes 4 lines!

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseWindowsFormsLifetime<Form1>();
var app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

Comment: You created custom bindings for the Application.xxx WinForms calls which normally occur in code before Application.Run(Form) is called however what if I want to do custom calls e.g. connect to the database before the form is shown?

Comment: Related [GitHub thread](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/discussions/6184#discussioncomment-5849260).